# OpenGL textures, SDL_TTF fonts and the power of two dimentions

Tags: opengl, fonts, textures, dimensions, sld

With my current project I've begun to translate all rendering from SDL to OpenGL. This means that I have to translate a SDL_Surface (a loaded img) to a OpenGL texture.

When I do this I understand that it's important for the dimensions to be of the power of two. But when I create a font I can't always have it of the power of two. In a tutorial which described how to use SDL_TTF with OpenGL it made sure to transform the image to the right dimensions if it weren't, but this only distorts my image.

If i don't mess with the dimensions everything works fine. Why do i need the power of two in dimensions? And if i really need it, how do i apply it without distorting my image?

Comment: The most important reason for power of two textures today is mipmapping. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mipmap Be aware: Depending on your target platform (and your gpu), the textures don't have to be power-of-two textures. See also: http://www.opengl.org/wiki/NPOT_Texture - Could you provide us some code you used to transform the image into the pot dimensions? And maybe also an example of the 'distortion'? Probably you're stretching the image instead of just add blank space

Comment: On this link:http://content.gpwiki.org/index.php/SDL:Tutorials:Using_SDL_with_OpenGL

Under the title "How To Load an OpenGL Texture from an SDL_Surface" will you find my transformation method. The only thing changed is that when it finds out that the texture is not to the power of two it changes it to it. I dont have access to that code now since i'm not at home but i'll post it as soon as i get home!